# Tensorial functions

Tags: function-construction, tensors

I need to solve a system of ODEs for a function that has a complicated tensorial structure. I believe that `NDSolve` can deal with this scenario since version 9. Yet, in some cases it cannot figure out the dimensionality of the dependent variable from the initial conditions. That is why I want to map a tensorial function onto a tensor of functions. I do as follows:

**Vector** (rank-1):

```
Through[Array[y, {2}][t]]
(* {y[1][t], y[2][t]} *)
```

**Matrix** (rank-2):

```
Through /@ Through[Array[y, {2, 2}][t]]
(* {{y[1, 1][t], y[1, 2][t]}, {y[2, 1][t], y[2, 2][t]}} *)
```

**Tensor** (rank-3, naïve approach does not work):

```
Through /@ Through /@ Through[Array[y, {2, 2, 2}][t]]
```

**Q**. What is the proper way of automatically obtaining a rank-$k$ tensorial function?

### Why is it needed?

The main goal is to minimize syntactic sugar for solving tensorial ODEs.

**1**. I will start from an example that can be found in the manual for `NDSolve`:

```
a={{1,  1,  1,  1},{1,  2,  1,  2},{1,  1,  3,  1},{1,  2,  1,  4}};
b={1,1,1,1};
NDSolve[{y''[x]+a.y[x]==0,y'[0]==y[0]==b},y,{x,0,8}]
```

This is a standard approach, where MA automatically figures out that `y[x]` is a *vector*. Nice.

**2**. But we can do the same slightly differently:

```
z[x_]=Through[Array[Y,{4}][x]];
s1=NDSolve[Join[Thread[z''[x]+a.z[x]==0],Thread[z'[0]==z[0]==b]],Array[Y,{4}],{x,0,8}];
```

MA solves here for 4 *scalar functions* instead `{Y[1][x],Y[2][x],Y[3][x],Y[4][x]}`, which is sometimes preferable. We can plot them as follows

```
Plot[Evaluate[z[x]/.s1],{x,0,8}]
```

**3**. Now, define a *matrix* function (two equivalent ways are possible)

```
w[x_]=Table[Y[i,j][x],{i,4},{j,4}]
w[x_]=Through/@Through[Array[Y,{4,4}][x]]
```

Notice that adding a dimension makes the syntax less and less transparent, and the commands become lengthier. Nonetheless, we can solve also this problem

```
s2=NDSolve[Join[Thread/@Thread[w''[x]+a.w[x]==0],Thread/@Thread[w'[0]==w[0]==a]]//Flatten,
    Array[Y,{4,4}]//Flatten,{x,0,8}];
Plot[Evaluate[w[x]/.s2],{x,0,8}]
```

What is disturbing is that going from a vector to a matrix equation more and more syntactic sugar needs to be added, like `Thread/@Thread` and `Flatten`. And it will be even less transparent for *tensorial* functions.

**Extended question**. What can be done to reduce this burden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want in the first part of your question using a `Map` and the levels argument. I've packed this into a function so you can change the function `y`, dimension, tensor-rank, or argument list (currently just `{t}`) if needs be:

```
genTensor[v_, dim_, rank_, args_] :=
  Map[Apply[#, args] &, Array[v, ConstantArray[dim, rank]], {rank}] 

(* 2d vector *)
genTensor[y,2,1,{t}]
(* result: {y[1][t], y[2][t]} *)

(* 2d matrix *)
genTensor[y,2,2,{t}]
(* result: {{y[1, 1][t], y[1, 2][t]}, {y[2, 1][t], y[2, 2][t]}} *)

(* 2d 3-tensor *)
genTensor[y,2,3,{t}]
(* result: {{{y[1, 1, 1][t], y[1, 1, 2][t]}, {y[1, 2, 1][t], y[1, 2, 2][t]}},
   {{y[2, 1, 1][t], y[2, 1, 2][t]},  {y[2, 2, 1][t], y[2, 2, 2][t]}}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you, it is nice to have this approach.